# React Native app - crash/close on startup on Android 8 real device

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I have a React Native project (not Expo) initialized with `react native init myapp`.
I can run this application on Emulator and Real Device with Android 5, but cannot run the app on my Android Mobile with Android 8.

Here's the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.1",
    "iso-639-1": "^2.0.3",
    "jsrsasign": "^8.0.12",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.8.3",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.6",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-persian-calendar-picker": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-settings-list": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-simple-dialogs": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^1.0.0",
    "realm": "^2.24.0",
    "yup": "^0.26.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.86.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation|react-navigation-redux-helpers)"
    ]
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tested it on Genymotion emulator with Android 5 and on a real LG device with Android 5 too and **everything works fine**.

But lately, I tried to run this project on an *Honor 8X* device with Android 8. But the application will be closed without any error just after getting JS Bundle from Metro!

- Run command: `react-native run-android`

It's the log from `react-native log-android`:

```
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
03-05 23:28:52.567  5513  5513 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
03-05 23:28:52.604  5513  5513 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
03-05 23:28:52.604  5513  5513 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
03-05 23:29:32.605  5513  5513 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
03-05 23:29:32.608  5513  5513 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
03-05 23:29:32.608  5513  5513 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
03-05 23:29:32.642  5513  5617 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
```

Just after the last line appears, the application will be closed on the device!

- Also, I gave all of the permissions to the app, including *Draw on other apps*, *Storage* permission and also excluded it from *Battery Saver*...

Here's the Metro Bundler output (which looks fine):

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
 DELTA  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1169/1169), done.

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2019:20:02:17 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
```

- I tried to run a **Hello World** application on my Honor 8X device and it runs successfully, so I think there's no problem with device and Android...
- Also considering that `myapp` runs successfully on Emulator and Device with Android 5, I'm completely confused... Maby there's a problem with one of *Dependencies*

Environment:
- Windows 10 Enterprise

Android Specific Files:
**`android/build.gradle`**:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

**`android/gradle.properties`**:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

**`android/app/build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
import com.android.build.OutputFile
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.mokhtaresho.tnet.users"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':realm')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-document-picker')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: can you give your  Build.gradle file from android directory.........need to see sdk versions

Comment: Thanks for comment @AshutoshPatel - I added files, Check the question again...

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to clear the cache? Usually with something like this:

```
rm package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*
rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-*
npm cache clean
npm install
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

But you probably need to remove only the metro and haste map cache. Sorry if you already tried that.

Comment: I would add `./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue with xiomi and realm.

Started testing on moto device worked fine.

It looks like v0.58.0 of react-native isn't compatible/ breaks something in realm as of now;
a temporary solution will be to initialize your RN project using v0.57.8

Steps:
react-native init --version="react-native@0.57.8" projectName
cd projectName
npm install realm --save
react-native link

And it should work

Comment: Thanks, I think so too, I removed Realm :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code from

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```

into

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
```