# How can I prevent my android app from crashing? (Logcat included)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, logcat

I've been dealing with an issue for the last couple of hours and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.
Everytime I launch my react native app, it crashes with no error message.
I tried running `adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S` and here's the result that I got:

```
--------- beginning of main
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of crash
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.wefix, PID: 23728
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to attach a rootView to ReactInstance when UIManager is not properly initialized.
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1140)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootView(ReactInstanceManager.java:816)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.attachToReactInstanceManager(ReactRootView.java:582)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactRootView.java:396)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactRootView.java:359)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$2.createRootView(ReactInstanceManager.java:313)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerBase.createRootView(DevSupportManagerBase.java:356)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.devsupport.LogBoxModule$1.run(LogBoxModule.java:40)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
01-11 01:34:05.413 23728 23728 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, did u find any reason why it was occurring and how did u resolve it ?

Comment: I'm currently facing the same problem. Did you end up finding a solution for it?

Answer (score -1):

Please try to Debugging code, and no one can help cause for a solution you need to have a proper error. you can use **if else** or **try catch** for save your app from crashing. find a error first and then ask for solution. all the best

1. maybe this will help you [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020848/react-native-app-crash-close-on-startup-on-android-8-real-device)